# Schema checking in structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a topic in Kafka I'm consuming, and I'm using from_json to convert the JSON message into a dataframe and I'm using structured streaming.

```scala
val agentStringDF = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("subscribe", "testTopic")
      .option("startingOffsets" , "latest")
      .load()

val df = agentStringDF.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), testTopicSchema).alias("testTopic"))
```

Is there any way to do some type of type with the from_json, that if it fails, log the error and move on to the next micro batch?

I have seen cases of checking the schema once it has been converted.. but nothing checking in this way.

Comment: `from_json` shouldn't fail no matter the data, so it is not clear what you expect.

Comment: so if the schema is wrong, I want the whole microbatch to be scrapped and nothing else done but logg the error. The scenario is a message committed to a topic is a breaking schema change, I want the spark job to be flexible enough to ignore bad messages.